# decimal.Decimal(float) vs. decimal.Decimal.from_float(float)

Tags: python, decimal

I'm a newbie in Python programming and lately I've been learning some aspects of data types. As I read, the method **decimal.Decimal()** creates a decimal object; **decimal.Decimal.from_float()** method creates a decimal object from a float object. However, both produce the same output:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> x = 3.14561
>>> y = 3.14561
>>> x = decimal.Decimal.from_float(x)
>>> y = decimal.Decimal(y)
>>> x == y

True
```

So, what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs, before Python 2.7 the Decimal() constructor could not take a float argument, which is why you needed the from_float() class method

Starting with 2.7, the constructor can also take a float directly, so the two are the same.

Still from the docs, I suppose the reason why constructing from float was initially disallowed is that:

> Note Decimal.from_float(0.1) is not the same as Decimal(‘0.1’). Since
>   0.1 is not exactly representable in binary floating point, the value is stored as the nearest representable value which is
>   0x1.999999999999ap-4. That equivalent value in decimal is
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625.

Comment: According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.from_float), `from_float` was added in 2.7 as well, i.e., at the same time as float support was added to the constructor.

Comment: +1 I agree that's the reason. Not every decimal values can be represented in a float.

Comment: @Blair: I think what that comment means is that in 2.7 the constructor was extended to also accept a float - not that from_float() is new in 2.7 - if both had been introduced at the same time, one would be redundant

Comment: The note in blue box is about it being added to the constructor. The italicised note at the end says the from_float method was added in 2.7. Compare it to the other methods e.g., `fma` - the italicised notes refers to the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

per [the Python3 Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.from_float),

```
Note: From Python 2.7 onwards, a Decimal instance can also be constructed directly from a float.
```

So as long as you're running Python 2.7+, nothing.